# How to remove jitter/shaking in my special application of OrbitControl and PerspectiveCamera?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, matrix-multiplication

In the live snippet below (also at https://jsfiddle.net/gpolyn/bpo7t7f6), I offer optional dynamic updating of PerspectiveCamera's `lookAt` parameter and `fov` in the [three.js](http://threejs.org/) render cycle. (My goal is to fill as much of the viewport as possible with the subject cube, through all orbit positions.)

**I suspect that lack of precision in the matrix math code used to calculate my dynamic `fov` and `lookAt` paramters (three.js [uses `Float32` arrays](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Matrix4.js)) causes the jitter/shaking I notice in the cube when orbiting with the dynamic options selected from the controls**. 
(The matrix operations can be found in the snippet `addExtrema` function.)

In my demo, **my highest goal is to remove jitter/shaking in case 1**, described here:

1. the "dynamicFovAndLookAt" control option uses dynamic `fov` and `lookAt` updating causing quite a bit of jitter in the cube, no matter the orbit position; the `fov` and `lookAt` parameters can be seen fluctuating in the demo's lower right status box;
2. "dynamicFov" uses dynamic `fov` updating causing some jitter in the cube, depending on orbiting; the `fov` parameter in the lower right status box will vary due to the dynamic recalculation;
3. the "boundingSphere" option uses no dynamic `fov`, `lookAt` updating and the cube exhibits no jitter/shake through orbiting – the `fov` and `lookAt` parameters are constant in the lower right status box.

(Orbit position is reported in the lower left corner of the demo, while one of the box corners has a green dot to aid any discussion of the jitter effect.)

```js
 var renderer, scene, camera, controls;
 var object;
 var vertices3;
 var cloud;
 var boxToBufferAlphaMapping = {
   0: 0,
   2: 1,
   1: 2,
   3: 4,
   6: 7,
   7: 10,
   5: 8,
   4: 6
 }
 var lastAlphas = [];
 var canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
 var windowMatrix;
 var boundingSphere;
 var figure;
 var fovWidth, fovDistance, fovHeight;
 var newFov, newLookAt;
 var dist, height, fov, lookAt;
 var aspect;
 var CONSTANT_FOR_FOV_CALC = 180 / Math.PI;
 var mat3;
 var CORNERS = 8;
 var ndc = new Array(CORNERS);
 var USE_GREEN_DOTS = false;
 var stats, orbitPosition, cameraFacts;
 var useDynamicFov;
 var datGuiData = {};


 init();
 render();
 afterInit();
 animate();

 function init() {

   mat3 = new THREE.Matrix4();

   canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
   canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
   aspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
   // renderer
   <!-- renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, logarithmicDepthBuffer:true}); -->
   renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
     antialias: true
   });
   renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   // scene
   scene = new THREE.Scene();

   // object
   var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 6);

   // too lazy to add edges without EdgesHelper...
   var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     transparent: true,
     opacity: 0
   });
   var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
   object = cube;

   // bounding sphere used for orbiting control in render
   object.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
   boundingSphere = object.geometry.boundingSphere;

   cube.position.set(2, 2, 3)
     // awkward, but couldn't transfer cube position to sphere...
   boundingSphere.translate(new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, 3));

   // save vertices for subsequent use
   vertices = cube.geometry.vertices;

   var edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper(cube)
   scene.add(edges);
   scene.add(cube);

   <!-- if (USE_GREEN_DOTS) addGreenDotsToScene(geometry); -->
   addGreenDotsToScene(geometry);

   // camera
   <!-- camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 17, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 20, 40 ); -->
   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(17, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
   camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);

   // controls
   controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
   controls.maxPolarAngle = 0.5 * Math.PI;
   controls.minAzimuthAngle = 0;
   controls.maxAzimuthAngle = 0.5 * Math.PI;
   controls.enableZoom = false;

   // performance monitor
   stats = new Stats();
   document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);

   // orbitposition tracker
   orbitPosition = new THREEg.OrbitReporter()
   orbitPosition.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
   orbitPosition.domElement.style.left = '0px'
   orbitPosition.domElement.style.bottom = '0px'
   document.body.appendChild(orbitPosition.domElement)

   // camera facts
   cameraFacts = new THREEg.CameraReporter()
   cameraFacts.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
   cameraFacts.domElement.style.right = '0px'
   cameraFacts.domElement.style.bottom = '0px'
   document.body.appendChild(cameraFacts.domElement)

   // ambient
   scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222));

   // axes
   scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(20));

   // initial settings
   dist = boundingSphere.distanceToPoint(camera.position);
   height = boundingSphere.radius * 2;
   fov = 2 * Math.atan(height / (2 * dist)) * (CONSTANT_FOR_FOV_CALC);
   newFov = fov;
   lookAt = new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, 3); // center of box
   newLookAt = lookAt;

   // dat.gui
   window.onload = function() {
     var view = datGuiData;
     view.boundingSphere = true;
     view.dynamicFov = false;
     view.dynamicFovAndLookAt = false;

     var gui = new dat.GUI();

     var CB1Controller = gui.add(view, 'boundingSphere').listen();
     CB1Controller.onChange(function(value) {
       view.boundingSphere = true;
       view.dynamicFov = false;
       view.dynamicFovAndLookAt = false;
     });

     var CB2Controller = gui.add(view, 'dynamicFov').listen();
     CB2Controller.onChange(function(value) {
       view.boundingSphere = false;
       view.dynamicFov = true;
       view.dynamicFovAndLookAt = false;
     });

     var CB3Controller = gui.add(view, 'dynamicFovAndLookAt').listen();
     CB3Controller.onChange(function(value) {
       view.boundingSphere = false;
       view.dynamicFov = true;
       view.dynamicFovAndLookAt = true;
     });
   };

 }

 function addExtrema() {

   // thread A  
   mat3.multiplyMatrices(camera.matrixWorld, mat3.getInverse(camera.projectionMatrix));

   // thread B 
   var scratchVar;

   var topIdx, bottomIdx, leftIdx, rightIdx;
   var top = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
   var bottom = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   var right = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
   var left = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   var closestVertex, closestVertexDistance = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   var vtx;

   for (var i = 0; i < CORNERS; i++) {

     scratchVar = vertices3[i].clone().applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorldInverse);
     scratchVar.applyMatrix4(camera.projectionMatrix);

     scratchVar.divideScalar(scratchVar.w)
     ndc[i] = scratchVar;

     vtx = ndc[i];

     if (vtx.x < left) {
       left = vtx.x;
       leftIdx = i;
     } else if (vtx.x > right) {
       right = vtx.x;
       rightIdx = i;
     }

     if (vtx.y < bottom) {
       bottom = vtx.y;
       bottomIdx = i;
     } else if (vtx.y > top) {
       top = vtx.y;
       topIdx = i;
     }

     if (vtx.z < closestVertexDistance) {
       closestVertex = i;
       closestVertexDistance = vtx.z;
     }

   }

   var yNDCPercentCoverage = (Math.abs(ndc[topIdx].y) + Math.abs(ndc[bottomIdx].y)) / 2;
   yNDCPercentCoverage = Math.min(1, yNDCPercentCoverage);

   var xNDCPercentCoverage = (Math.abs(ndc[leftIdx].x) + Math.abs(ndc[rightIdx].x)) / 2;
   xNDCPercentCoverage = Math.min(1, xNDCPercentCoverage);

   var ulCoords = [ndc[leftIdx].x, ndc[topIdx].y, closestVertexDistance, 1]
   var blCoords = [ndc[leftIdx].x, ndc[bottomIdx].y, closestVertexDistance, 1]
   var urCoords = [ndc[rightIdx].x, ndc[topIdx].y, closestVertexDistance, 1]

   var ul = new THREE.Vector4().fromArray(ulCoords);
   ul.applyMatrix4(mat3).divideScalar(ul.w);

   var bl = new THREE.Vector4().fromArray(blCoords);
   bl.applyMatrix4(mat3).divideScalar(bl.w);

   var ur = new THREE.Vector4().fromArray(urCoords);
   ur.applyMatrix4(mat3).divideScalar(ur.w);

   var center = new THREE.Vector3();
   center.addVectors(ur, bl);
   center.divideScalar(2);

   var dist = camera.position.distanceTo(center);


   var upperLeft = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(ul.toArray().slice(0, 3));
   var p;

   if ((1 - yNDCPercentCoverage) < (1 - xNDCPercentCoverage)) { // height case
     var bottomLeft = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(bl.toArray().slice(0, 3));
     var height = upperLeft.distanceTo(bottomLeft);
     p = 2 * Math.atan(height / (2 * dist)) * (CONSTANT_FOR_FOV_CALC);
   } else { // width case
     var upperRight = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(ur.toArray().slice(0, 3));
     var width = upperRight.distanceTo(upperLeft);
     p = 2 * Math.atan((width / aspect) / (2 * dist)) * (CONSTANT_FOR_FOV_CALC);
   }

   if (datGuiData.dynamicFovAndLookAt || datGuiData.dynamicFov) {
     newFov = p;
   } else {
     dist = boundingSphere.distanceToPoint(camera.position);
     height = boundingSphere.radius * 2;
     newFov = 2 * Math.atan(height / (2 * dist)) * (CONSTANT_FOR_FOV_CALC);
   }

   if (datGuiData.dynamicFovAndLookAt == true) {
     newLookAt = center;
   } else {
     newLookAt = lookAt;
   }

   if (USE_GREEN_DOTS) {
     var alphas = cloud.geometry.attributes.alpha;

     // make last points invisible
     lastAlphas.forEach(function(alphaIndex) {
       alphas.array[alphaIndex] = 0.0;
     });
     // now, make new points visible...
     // (boxToBufferAlphaMapping is a BufferGeometry-Object3D geometry
     // map between the object and green dots)
     alphas.array[boxToBufferAlphaMapping[rightIdx]] = 1.0;
     alphas.array[boxToBufferAlphaMapping[bottomIdx]] = 1.0;
     alphas.array[boxToBufferAlphaMapping[topIdx]] = 1.0;
     alphas.array[boxToBufferAlphaMapping[leftIdx]] = 1.0;

     // store visible points for next cycle
     lastAlphas = [boxToBufferAlphaMapping[rightIdx]];
     lastAlphas.push(boxToBufferAlphaMapping[bottomIdx])
     lastAlphas.push(boxToBufferAlphaMapping[topIdx])
     lastAlphas.push(boxToBufferAlphaMapping[leftIdx])

     alphas.needsUpdate = true;
   }

 }

 function addGreenDotsToScene(geometry) {

   var bg = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
   bg.fromGeometry(geometry);
   bg.translate(2, 2, 3); // yucky, and quick

   var numVertices = bg.attributes.position.count;
   var alphas = new Float32Array(numVertices * 1); // 1 values per vertex

   <!-- for( var i = 0; i < numVertices; i ++ ) { -->
   <!--     alphas[ i ] = 1; -->
   <!-- } -->

   alphas[2] = 1;

   bg.addAttribute('alpha', new THREE.BufferAttribute(alphas, 1));

   var uniforms = {
     color: {
       type: "c",
       value: new THREE.Color(0x00ff00)
     },
   };

   var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
     uniforms: uniforms,
     vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
     fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
     transparent: true
   });

   cloud = new THREE.Points(bg, shaderMaterial);
   scene.add(cloud);

 }

 function afterInit() {

   windowMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
   windowMatrix.set(canvasWidth / 2, 0, 0, canvasWidth / 2, 0, canvasHeight / 2, 0, canvasHeight / 2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1);

   var vertices2 = object.geometry.vertices.map(function(vtx) {
     return (new THREE.Vector4(vtx.x, vtx.y, vtx.z));
   });

   // create 'world-space' geometry points, using
   // model ('world') matrix
   vertices3 = vertices2.map(function(vt) {
     return vt.applyMatrix4(object.matrixWorld);
   })

 }

 function render() {

   <!-- console.log({far: camera.far, camera_near: camera.near}) -->
   camera.lookAt(newLookAt);
   camera.fov = newFov;
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   renderer.render(scene, camera);

 }

 function animate() {

   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   render();
   addExtrema()
   stats.update();
   orbitPosition.update(controls);
   cameraFacts.update(camera, newLookAt);

 }
```

```css
   body {
     background-color: #000;
     margin: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .dg .c {
     width: 40%
   }
   .dg .property-name {
     width: 60%
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/gpolyn/789d63a662c1768320756f68a6099f15/raw/3a0f323bb284b09e624a11f93ff4055e23adea80/OrbitReporter.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/gpolyn/70352cb34c7900ed2489400d4ecc45f7/raw/7b6e7e6bb3e175d4145879ef1afdeb38c31cf785/camera_reporter.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

  attribute float alpha; varying float vAlpha; void main() { vAlpha = alpha; vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); gl_PointSize = 8.0; gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition; }

</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

  uniform vec3 color; varying float vAlpha; void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4( color, vAlpha ); }

</script>
```

Comment: Do not go behind the back of `OrbitControls` and call `camera.lookAt()` yourself. You can call `controls.target.set( x, y, z )` if you want.

Comment: @WestLangley helpful to know, but not directly useful, as it doesn't impact my dynamic fov calculation.

Comment: Your question was about how to remove the jittering.

Comment: Do not reset the target in the render loop. Set a good target and hold it constant.

Comment: @WestLangley done at https://jsfiddle.net/gpolyn/bpo7t7f6/3/ (see line 130), but its not really a solution, because 1) I reset the target dynamically to ensure the cube is precisely in the center when fov is changed to fit the new perspective and 2) fov is not impacted, so there is still jitter. In other words, your workaround subtracts from my goal: keep the cube fully in the viewport through all orbit positions.

Comment: @WestLangley I marked your last remark as helpful, because on review of jsfiddle.net/gpolyn/bpo7t7f6/3, it definitely makes shaking more manageable under my scenario 2 (though my scenario 1 is still outstanding for me.)